# Spoilage percentage and field of tolerance

Tags: probability

Internal diameter of a pipe is $5cm$ with tolerance $\pm0.1cm$.

a) Determine the spoilage percentage (spoilage is outside of tolerance interval) if the processing on the machine gives the standard deviation $\sigma=0.08cm$.

b) Determine the field of tolerance in order to reduce the spoilage to $5\%$.

**Question**: How to solve this problem?

Comment: How is the internal diameter distributed, normal ?

Comment: @callculus, that is not specified.

Comment: In this case it is difficult or even impossible to solve it.

Comment: @callculus, I think that we must recognize the type of distribution, just like we must recognize variations, permutations and combinations in combinatorics.

Comment: I´m almost sure that the internal diameter is normally distributed. But it cannot be derived from the text. I have seen this situation in many questions here on MSE. Maybe the general topic is normal distribution.

Comment: @callculus, It is the normal distribution because of the $\sigma$ parameter.